# JQ see if a value exists

Tags: json, bash, jq

Having a JSON object like:

```
[{"My$Val":[{"Sub1":"val1", "pld":"s"}]},{"My$Val":[{"Sub1":"val2", "pld":"q"}]}]
```

What I would like to do using jq, is see if there exists any key of Sub1, that contains the value val2.

So in the above JSON-document, the output should yield true.

I've been trying a bit but I do not have a solid grasp on jq yet. Trying to build it step by step I am getting a syntax error when I try to get the values on Sub1.

```
 echo '[{"My$Val":[{"Sub1":"val1", "pld":"s"}]},{"My$Val":[{"Sub1":"val2", "pld":"q"}]}]' | jq .[]."My$Val".[]."Sub1"
```

Error:

```
 jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
        .[].My.[].Sub1    


    jq: 1 compile error
```

Comment: The problem comes from your shell consuming the quotes: `jq '.[]."My$Val".[]."Sub1"'` should fix it. With your jq program unquoted, what jq receives is `.[].My.[].Sub1` which is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax error is caused by the shell consuming the quotes. When `jq .[]."My$Val"` is parsed by the shell, jq only receives `.[].My` as argument.
Where did the quotes go? Your shell consumed them.
Where did `$Val` go? `$` expands a parameter/variable and since `Val` is not defined as variable in your environment, it will be replaced with the empty/null string.

Read on for a solution to your actual problem, i.e. "how to return 'true' or 'false'"

---

You can use `any` to check items in a stream for a condition. If you first stream all leaf objects with `.[][][]`, then you can simply check the `Sub1` property for the expected value:

```
jq 'any(.[][][]; .Sub1 == "val2")'
```

(Yes, jq is magic.)

---

Longer explanation/example:

`.[][][]` returns a stream of your innermost objects:

```
{
  "Sub1": "val1",
  "pld": "s"
}
{
  "Sub1": "val2",
  "pld": "q"
}
```

Since your outer keys are always `My$Val`, you could use a "stricter" filter too to extract only `My$Val` objects: `.[]["My$Val"][]`

Complete program with specific key:

```
any(.[]["My$Val"][]; .Sub1 == "val2")
```

---

It is also possible to use the SQL-like `IN` operator to check if a stream of values contains a value:

```
IN(.[]["My$Val"][].Sub1; "val2")
```

(`IN` itself is internally implemented using `any`)

Comment: Could you also explain how I feed the entire JSON-object into it. For example echo'ing the JSON inside the first step of a pipe? In both the `any` and `in` examples I am missing how the JSON object is fed in to it.

Comment: When I try `echo '[{"My$Val":[{"Sub1":"val1", "pld":"s"}]},{"My$Val":[{"Sub1":"val2", "pld":"q"}]}]' | any(.[]["My$Val"][]; .Sub1 == "val2")`, it returns with an error `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `.[]["My$Val"][]'`.

Comment: @SomeDutchGuy what I showed is the jq program, i.e. the first argument to the `jq` command. I assumed this was known, since this is a jq question and you already called `jq` in the question. jq can read data from standard input (e.g. from a pipe or redirection) or from a file.